# PHP utf8 and json_encode accent mark problems

Tags: php

I have a text coming from a CSV full of accent marks.
I check if `mb_check_encoding($my_text, 'utf-8')` is true, and yes, it is.
With this text I generate a variable `$json` which apply a

```
json_encode($json,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

var_dump($json)
```

gives an array of arrays with all strange marks correct (é, ì, etc), but the generated JSON text is incorrect (ex: `"Donn\u00e9es"` instead of `"Données"`).

I know that `json_encode` only works fine for utf8 encoded data, that's why I checked it before that it was utf8. 
I tried also adding a `header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");` without success.

Then what could be the reason of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how JSON encodes "strange marks", i.e. Unicode characters. When you use `json_decode()` on your JSON-encoded string, it will return to normal.